# How to change max_line_length when running a DBT project?

Tags: sql, project, dbt, sqlfluff

I have a problem when run a DBT project. Some of my SQL commands are longer then the limit (80). So I have got the following error info:
[image]

I have tried to change the limit in dbt_project.yml and .sqlfluff. But none of the worked.

[image]

[image]

How to fix this problem and change the length limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a linter-related issue, so most probably nothing to do with your `dbt_project.yml`.

In order to correctly set a `max_line_length` value in your `.sqlfluff` file, you need to nest it under the `[sqlfluff]` tag. Meaning that your `.sqlfluff` file should look like this:

```
[sqlfluff]
dialect = snowflake
exclude_rules = L031
max_line_length = 120
```

See this example for SQLFluff's docs [here](https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/configuration.html#:%7E:text=max_line_length%20%3D%20120:%7E:text=%23%20The%20standard%20max_line_length%20is%2080%20in%20line%20with%20the%20convention%20of%0A%23%20other%20tools%20and%20several%20style%20guides.%20Many%20projects%20however%20prefer%0A%23%20something%20a%20little%20longer.%0A%23%20Set%20to%20zero%20or%20negative%20to%20disable%20checks.%0Amax_line_length%20%3D%20120).